grub conflicts with grub2

What should I do now?
I want to add windows 10 into grub so is grub2  recommended?
I renew   /usr/sbin/update-grub  :
exec grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg "$@"  

======>
exec grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg "$@"  

so do I need install grub2 ?
my system is debian 12.

Debian 12 already comes with the Grub version it needs.

For dual-booting you must assure both OSes are installed in the same mode (and for any computer newer than 2012 that mode should always be UEFI mode, end of story) and with any Windows 8 or newer disabling its Fast Startup feature is a must, and that even before installing the Linux part. Failing or not understanding either one will translate into problems like the one both your questions stem from. What you think is solution, just isn't, it's a X-Y problem you got yourself into.
